# In app large adverts android

Tags: java, android, admob

I want to have a page between activities that displays ads full screen. This is for the free version of my app the paid removes these. But all I can find at the moment are smaller ads provided from people like admob.

Where do I find larger ones?

Comment: These are called "interstitials".  That might help in you in your search.

Answer (score 1):

I think AdMob does provide fullScreen Ads. You just have to search.
check this link: http://groups.google.com/group/admob-iphone-sdk/browse_thread/thread/d070a92c0ec16d9c
It is Admob who selects the publisher who can publish fullScreen Ads

Comment: Are there any other places that provide these without selection

Comment: check the following links:
http://blog.mobclix.com/2011/01/26/make-more-money-with-the-full-screen-ad-unit/

Comment: http://www.androidacademy.com/forum/3-discussion/267-greystripe-brings-fullscreen-android-ads-video